# Checking LDAP Connectivity CAS 3.4.12

Tags: ldap, cas, spring-ldap

I have a CAS 3.4.12 set up integrated with LDAP.

Everything works great but if the LDAP or AD server goes down then CAS server throws exception and displays CAS is unavailable exception.

What I am trying to do is that I want to check during the page load whether LDAP is connected or not.

If not then hide the username and password fields so that users are unable to enter the credentials.

Any Pointers or suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the form is displayed, and then LDAP goes down?

What happens when the form is displayed, user fills out the form and submits, then LDAP goes down

Comment: I would like to send a boolean to the front end to disable the text fields so that no user can login. 

for point #2 I will be checking on login as well. If LDAP goes down then also I will have to redirect the user back to login page with fields disabled and a proper message on casLoginView.jsp

Comment: my major concern is that when cas is up and running. If LDAP/AD goes down then since user can see the login page then they keep posting login requests. eventually we end up having lots of Close_Wait Connection on ssl port, we have to eventually restart the servers. So any pointers or suggestions will help me and my team resolve this issue. 

Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably solve this issue with what you have in mind. Specially if you have multiple CAS nodes. You should either trap the exception and adjust the flow to route to an "error" screen explaining what happened, add redundancy to your LDAP/AD infrastructure or see if CAS throttling can help you block authn attempts.